# Why isn't my jquery script showing proper score?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Raty and I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/raty/js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript"> 
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.yourrating').each(function(index,elem){
            $(elem).raty({
                readOnly:  false,
                path: "{{ STATIC_URL }}js/raty/img/",
                score: $(elem).children("span:first").text(),
                click: function(score, evt) {
                    var vote_url = "/spice/rate/" + this.id.substring(2) + "/" + score + "/";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: vote_url,
                        success: function(){
                            alert('vote successful');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            $('.thingrating').raty({
                readOnly: true,
                path: "{{ STATIC_URL }}js/raty/img/",
                score: $(elem).children("span:first").text(),
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

The first script `yourrating` is working and allows people to rate the item. It is implemented as follows:

`<div class="yourrating" id="t_{{ item.id }}"><span style="display:none;">{{score}}</span></div>`

The second script `thingrating` is not working. It should show the current score of the model. It is implemented in the template as follows:

`<div class="thingrating" id="t_{{ item.id }}"><span style="display:none;">{{score}}</span></div>`

Why isn't the second script working? It's displaying the stars, but not the score. If I hardcode the score with `4` instead of `{{score}}` that also has no effect -- the stars remain blank.

Here's live code from my browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr"
xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>


Welcomes         

component Description 


    </title>

        <!--[if IE]>
            <style>
                div { zoom: 1; /* trigger hasLayout */ }
            </style>
            <![endif]-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/reset.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.css" />
            <!--Scripts -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
                document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/site_media/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
            }
            </script>
            <script src="/site_media/static/pinax/js/base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/site_media/static/uni_form/uni-form.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>





<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/comments.css" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed' rel='stylesheet'
type='text/css'>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/css/reset_tabs.css"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/css/site_tabs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/avatar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/blogs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/friends.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/groups.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/locations.css"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/nav.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/messages.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/microblogging.css"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/pagination.css"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/photos.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/tabs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/topics.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/pinax/css/wiki.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/bookmarks/css/bookmarks.css"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site_media/static/spices/css/spices.css"
/>
--> 




    </head>

<body class="">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="brand" href="/"><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/logo_small_55.png " alt="book" width="173.4" height="46.75" /></a>




                        <div class="nav-collapse">


<ul class="nav"><li id="tab_profile"><a href="/profiles/profile/admin/">PROFILE</a></li><li id="tab_product_library"><a href="/spices/">PRODUCT DATA</a></li><li id="tab_product_library"><a href="/spices/book_library">book LIBRARY</a></li><li class="dropdown pull-right" id = "community"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">COMMUNITY</a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="/profiles">Search </a></li><li><a href="/questions/">Questions and Answers</a></li><li><a href="/spices/view_requests/"> Requests</a></li><li><a href="/">Latest Updates</a></li></ul></li></ul> 





<ul class="nav pull-right">

    <li class="dropdown pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="badge badge-warning">(2)</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/notices/">All notifications</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="/messages/inbox/">Messages</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="/invitations/">Invitations</a></li>


        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">


             <!--<b>
                admin
            </b> -->
            <img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/icons/gear.png" width = "20" height = "20" alt="" />

            <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <li><a href="/profiles/edit">Edit Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="/spices/your_components">Manage Parts</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/account/email/">Account</a>
            </li>

            <li><a href="/admin/">Admin</a></li>

            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="/account/logout/">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>






                            <form class="navbar-search pull-right" value = "" action="/search/?q=">
                                <input type="text" class="search-query span2" name = "q" placeholder="Search">
                                <i class="icon-search icon-white" onclick=""></i>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /navbar-inner -->
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid ">



                    <div id="left_tabs"></div>
                    <div id="right_tabs" ></div> 

                    <div id="body">


                    <div class=" row-fluid" id="subnav-outer">
                        <div class="pull-right" id="subnav-inner">

                        </div>
                    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/site_media/static/js/raty/js/jquery.raty.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript"> 
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.yourrating').each(function(index,elem){
            $(elem).raty({
                readOnly:  false,
                path: "/site_media/static/js/raty/img/",
                score: $(elem).children("span:first").text(),
                click: function(score, evt) {
                    var vote_url = "/spices/rate/" + this.id.substring(2) + "/" + score + "/";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: vote_url,
                        success: function(){
                            alert('vote successful');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            $('.thingrating').raty({
                readOnly: true,
                path: "/site_media/static/js/raty/img/",
                score: $(elem).children("span:first").text(),
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>


<div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- component image -->
    <div class="span2">
        <div class="row-fluid align-center">
            <img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/library_placeholders/component.png">
            <br><br>
            <!-- Future CODE <div class="coverart"><img src=/site_media/media/ /></div>-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <!-- component Name -->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <h3>
                    Book123: component for Books
                </h3>
            </div>
                    <fieldset class="inlineLabels">
                        <div class="thingrating" id="t_5"><span style="display:none;">3</span></div>
                    </fieldset>
            <div class="span6">


            </div>
 </div>
        <!-- Download Button -->
        <div class="row-fluid align-left">
            <a href="/site_media/media/bookParts/Book123-SDFKSDfsdfasd-component-Books-7.jpg" class="btn btn-medium btn-success" type="submit">Download component</a>
            <br>
<br>
<br>
 </div>
Please rate the quality of the component after downloading.
<br>
<br>
<div class="yourrating" id="t_5"><span style="display:none;">3</span></div>
<br>
<br>
  <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#relatedproducts" data-toggle="tab"><h6>Related Products (26)</h6></a>
                </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#relatedbookparts" data-toggle="tab"><h6>Related book Parts (2)</h6></a>
            </li>
            <li>

                <a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab"><h6>Comments (3)</h6></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
            <!-- SPECIFICATIONS - Use a for loop to run through the different specifications
            If not a spec sheet, just show the description -->
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="relatedproducts">
    <table class="table">

      <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/323/view_part">OAK 7-140</a></td>
        <td><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/company_logos/thumbs/Other Vendor.jpg" height="30" width='100' /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/327/view_part">OAK 7-14MM</a></td>
        <td><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/company_logos/thumbs/Other Vendor.jpg" height="30" width='100' /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/325/view_part">Book123AMH</a></td>
        <td><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/company_logos/thumbs/Book Vendor.jpg" height="30" width='100' /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/320/view_part">Book123CH</a></td>
        <td><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/company_logos/thumbs/Book Vendor.jpg" height="30" width='100' /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/324/view_part">Book123MH</a></td>
        <td><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/company_logos/thumbs/Book Vendor.jpg" height="30" width='100' /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/322/view_part">Book123H</a></td>
        <td><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/company_logos/thumbs/Book Vendor.jpg" height="30" width='100' /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/329/view_part">Book123H883C</a></td>
        <td><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/company_logos/thumbs/Book Vendor.jpg" height="30" width='100' /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/326/view_part">Book123H883</a></td>
        <td><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/company_logos/thumbs/Book Vendor.jpg" height="30" width='100' /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/321/view_part">Book123AH</a></td>
        <td><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/company_logos/thumbs/Book Vendor.jpg" height="30" width='100' /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/328/view_part">Book123MH883</a></td>
        <td><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/company_logos/thumbs/Book Vendor.jpg" height="30" width='100' /></td>
      </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a href = "/search/?q=Book123">View more</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="relatedbookparts">    
    <table class="table">

    <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/5/view_component">Book123</a></td>
        <td>component</td>
      </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a href = "/spices/4/view_component">Book123</a></td>
        <td>component</td>
      </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><a href = "/search/?q=Book123">View more</a></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="comments"> 










<ul class="responses">

    <li class="even thread-0 clearfix">
        <div class="meta">
            <div class="avatar"><img src="/site_media/media/avatars/mary/resized/40/avatars/mary/Beta.jpg" alt="mary" width="40" height="40" /></div>
            <div class="details"><a href="/profiles/profile/mary/">mary</a></div>
            Oct. 30, 2012
        </div>
        <div class="bulk">
            <div class="body"><p>It&#39;s ok but not great.</p></div>

            <a class="btn pull-left" href="javascript:toggle_comment_form(2)">Reply</a>
            <form class="hidden" method="POST" action="/comments/comment/76/5/2/" id="comment_form_2">
                <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='745d1d9de808f6067468636314711afa' /></div>
                <table><tr><td><textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="comment"></textarea></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Post Response" /></td></tr></table>
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/spices/5/view_component/" />
                </form>


            </div>
        </li>

    <li class="odd thread-1 clearfix">
        <div class="meta">
            <div class="avatar"><img src="/site_media/media/avatars/mary/resized/40/avatars/mary/Beta.jpg" alt="mary" width="40" height="40" /></div>
            <div class="details"><a href="/profiles/profile/mary/">mary</a></div>
            Oct. 30, 2012
        </div>
        <div class="bulk">
            <div class="body"><p>You should be cooler</p></div>

            <a class="btn pull-left" href="javascript:toggle_comment_form(4)">Reply</a>
            <form class="hidden" method="POST" action="/comments/comment/76/5/4/" id="comment_form_4">
                <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='745d1d9de808f6067468636314711afa' /></div>
                <table><tr><td><textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="comment"></textarea></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Post Response" /></td></tr></table>
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/spices/5/view_component/" />
                </form>


            </div>
        </li>

    <li class="even thread-0 clearfix">
        <div class="meta">
            <div class="avatar"><img src="/site_media/media/avatars/mary/resized/40/avatars/mary/Beta.jpg" alt="mary" width="40" height="40" /></div>
            <div class="details"><a href="/profiles/profile/mary/">mary</a></div>
            Oct. 30, 2012
        </div>
        <div class="bulk">
            <div class="body"><p>Ok cool</p></div>

            <a class="btn pull-left" href="javascript:toggle_comment_form(3)">Reply</a>
            <form class="hidden" method="POST" action="/comments/comment/76/5/3/" id="comment_form_3">
                <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='745d1d9de808f6067468636314711afa' /></div>
                <table><tr><td><textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="comment"></textarea></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Post Response" /></td></tr></table>
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/spices/5/view_component/" />
                </form>


            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>





    <fieldset class="inlineLabels">
        <form class="uniForm" method="POST" action="/comments/comment/76/5/">
            <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='745d1d9de808f6067468636314711afa' /></div>
            <div class="ctrlHolder">
                <label for="id_comment">Comment</label>
                <textarea id="id_comment" rows="10" cols="40" name="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form_block">
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/spices/5/view_component/" />
                <input type="submit" value="Post Response" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </fieldset>


    </div>
<br>
<br>
  </div>
</div>
   </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <table class="table" id="information-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="profile_avatar">
                                    <img src="/site_media/media/avatars/mary/resized/27/avatars/mary/Beta.jpg" alt="mary" width="27" height="27" />
                              </div>                    </td>
                        <td>Added by</td>
                        <td><a href="/profiles/profile/mary/">mary</a></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/icons/addedicon.png">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Added on
                        </td>
                        <td>October 30, 2012</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/icons/handsnap.png">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Downloads
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            193
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- Twitter Button -->
        <div class="row-fluid align-center">
            <a href="#twitterlink" class="btn valign-middle">
                Share
                <img class="small-twitter-icon" src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/icons/twitter-icon.png" alt="" width="22" height="18" />
            </a>
        </div>
<br>
        <div class="row-fluid align-center">
    <br>
<h4>Find More Books Libraries</h4>
<br>
<div class="details inline">
     <a rel="tooltip" href="/spices/bookparts/Books/component" title="components"><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/library_placeholders/component.png" width = "20%"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a rel="tooltip" href="/spices/bookparts/Books/component" title="components"><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/library_placeholders/component.png" width = "20%"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a rel="tooltip" href="/spices/bookparts/Books/component" title="components"><img src="/site_media/static/pinax/images/library_placeholders/component.png" width = "20%"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">
        <h3>

        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 align-center">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //javascript to send messages
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        //activate tooltips
        $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
    });

    function sendMessage(){
        //retrieve the inputs
        var form = $('#sendMessageForm');
        var recipient = form.find('#message_recipient');
        var subject = form.find('#message_subject');
        var body = form.find('#message_data');

        var fields = [recipient, subject, body];

        for(var i = 0; i <fields.length; i++){
            var field = fields[i];
            if(field.val() == ""){

                field.closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
                field.next('.help-inline').text('Please enter this field');
            }
            else{
                field.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            }
        }


        if(!fieldsNotFilled){
            $.ajax({
              url: '/messages/compose/',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '745d1d9de808f6067468636314711afa',
                recipient: recipient.val(),
                subject: subject.val(),
                body: body.val(),

            },
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {

            },


        });

        }      
    }

    </script>

                </div>


                <script src="/site_media/static/pinax/js/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
            loadingImage: '/site_media/static/pinax/img/facebox/loading.gif',
            closeImage: '/site_media/static/pinax/img/facebox/closelabel.gif'
        });
        $(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() {
            $("form.in_facebox").submit(function() {
                form = this;
                jQuery.facebox(function($) {
                    fields = jQuery(form).find("input[type='text']").filter(":enabled");
                    params = {}
                    fields.each(function() {
                        params[this.name] = this.value;
                    });
                    jQuery.post(form.action, params,
                        function(data, textStatus) {
                            jQuery.facebox(data);
                        }
                    );
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
     });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/site_media/static/pinax/js/topics.js">
</script>






            </div>

            <div id="push-footer"></div>
   </div>
        <div id="footer">
           <aside><p style="color:#1E90FF;background-color:white;text-align:center;font-size:125%;">
            Hi there, early book member! Want to provide a suggestion or report a bug? <a href="mailto:mary@book.com?subject=book: I have a comment&body=[sub]" onclick="this.href = this.href.replace('[sub]',window.location)"> Send Feedback</a>
            </p></aside>

<div id="footer-inner" class="row-fluid align-center">

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="legal">
            <span>&copy; 2012 book</span> -
            <a href="/about/">ABOUT US</a>
            -
            <a href="/about/terms/">TERMS OF SERVICE</a>
            -
            <a href="/about/privacy/">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
            -
            <a href="/blog/"> BLOG </a>
        </div>

</div>

 </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: post the live code from source view of browser

Comment: any errors thrown in browser console? You have a trailing comma that will throw error in IE for sure.

Comment: I'm using Firefox and Safari and no errors are thrown... but my template looks funny so I was thinking a </div> could be missing... where is the trailing comma?

Comment: comma on last line...run page through w3c validator regarding DIV problem. Other than that double check initialization code in the plugin API is all I can suggest

Comment: ok thanks. So other than that comma at the bottom of the page, the jquery and implementation looks fine??

Comment: comma last line of the script `score: $(elem).children("span:first").text(),`<===

Comment: Ok, thanks. That didn't fix it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that you are initializing `raty` on `'.thingrating'` inside `$.each()`? Try this:

```
<script type ="text/javascript"> 
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.yourrating').each(function(index,elem){
            $(elem).raty({
                readOnly:  false,
                path: "{{ STATIC_URL }}js/raty/img/",
                score: $(elem).children("span:first").text(),
                click: function(score, evt) {
                    var vote_url = "/spice/rate/" + this.id.substring(2) + "/" + score + "/";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: vote_url,
                        success: function(){
                            alert('vote successful');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        $('.thingrating').each(function(index, elem){
            $(elem).raty({
                readOnly: true,
                path: "{{ STATIC_URL }}js/raty/img/",
                score: $(elem).children("span:first").text()
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! This worked! I am so extremely grateful haha :-) This was stumping me for hours.